# How do I select if a column is null or not (as a boolean)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm making a database view in MS SQL server 2008 R2. One of the output columns, named 'Status', pulls information about an entity from several different tables to produce a string status that is reported to the user.

I'm therefore creating a function which takes the entity ID as the only parameter and returns the nvarchar(MAX) status.

The first check is whether or not the entity has been approved. This is stored in the database as the username of the person that approved it. If it is not approved, the value is NULL.

So, pseudo-code for what I want to do is this:

```
if entity is NOT approved
    return "Pending"
else
begin
    max = select MAX(value) from EntityStatus // several statuses may exist
    status = select name from EntityStatus WHERE value = max
    return status
end
```

My immediate problem is: How do I select the 'approved' boolean?

I'm very new to T-SQL programming (it probably shows) so feel free to suggest other ways I can improve my function.

Comment: If you're relying on EntityStatus.Value to be in ascending order without an explicit order-by column, may I suggest that you need one? Some day your system is going to need a status that you want to insert in between other statuses, and that may be very difficult to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (select approver_username from approvals where entityid = @entityid) is null
    return 'Pending'
else
begin
    ...
end
```

Comment: Note that if your query can return multiple rows then the IF statement will fail. Also, from a purely stylistic preference standpoint, I would prefer `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE approver_username IS NULL)` over the construction given.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
select city,isnull(city,'pending/unknown')city2 from authors
```